# Install BCM 4365 drivers in Backtrack 5R3

Tags: drivers, wifi, backtrack, broadcom

I have recently installed Backtrack 5 R3. When I try to run:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I get the following error:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.2.6 (x86_64)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/ for more information.
dpkg: error processing bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What does that mean and how can I fix it?

I followed the instructions from [a guide here on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69199/wireless-not-working-after-update-network-unclaimed/69207#69207).

---

#### /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/make.log

```
DKMS make.log for bcmwl-5.60.48.36+bdcom for kernel 3.2.6 (x86_64)
Wed Jul 10 21:04:16 PKT 2013
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-source-3.2.6'

  WARNING: Symbol version dump /usr/src/linux-source-3.2.6/Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

  LD      /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:219: error: unknown field ‘ndo_set_multicast_list’ specified in initializer
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:219: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘_wl_set_multicast_list’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1435: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘mc_list’
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1435: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘mc_count’
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1436: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1442: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-source-3.2.6'
```

Comment: Post the contents of `/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/make.log`.

Comment: What system are you using? Ubuntu 12.04LTS? 13.04?

Comment: No i am using Backtrack 5 R3

Dell Inspiron n5520